# Problem with code highlighting

Tags: support, code-formatting

See my answer here:

[I can't get this page to stop subtracting the xl sales from the total. classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693169/i-cant-get-this-page-to-stop-subtracting-the-xl-sales-from-the-total-classic-as/4693397#4693397)

I can't get the

```
rscommon.close
wend
```

lines to be in the code block, tried loads of things (even changing comments from ' to // to see if it helped).

I'm on Chrome, can anyone else reproduce this as well by editing my answer?

**Edit: to reproduce:**

- erg
- wef

  wefwef
  rscommon.close
  wend

Add the two list items, underneath them on single spaces lines add:

rscommon.close

wend

Then (without anything else after the code) select it and press format code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last two lines needed to be indented further so that with the additional list-item indent, they also had the required four-space indent for the code block like the previous lines had. I've gone ahead and made the change for you, though the `rscommon.close` line may need additional indentation (I wasn't sure).

Comment: Thanks for that, when I wrote all the code though it was all indented properly, and I selected all the code and pressed code format button and it just refused to do the last 2 lines though.

Comment: @TomGullen Ah, interesting...I'll see if I can reproduce that then and let you know what I find.

Comment: The <tr> line originally had a ... after it, and the comments were all single ' not //, if that affects anything.  Being directly underneath a list might have something to do with it as well.

Comment: I've reproduced it in this question, 1) add two list items, 2) underneath have rscommon.close <newline> wend 3) select and press format code